# How to Matlab code combining to make it easier

Tags: matlab

Hello I wanted to reshape this code to make it easier.

```
sins=1/3*(sind(50)+sind(300)+sind(340));
coses=1/3*(cosd(50)+cosd(300)+cosd(340));

result=atand(sins/coses);
```

it will be more input like 50,300,340... so I wanted to like this

```
a=[50 300 340];

sins=1/3*(sind(a));
coses=1/3*(cosd(b));

result=atand(sins/coses);
```

but it doesnt work.
How can I make it ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example, you sum all three values returned by `sind`, in your second code you don't sum them. Inputting a matrix, `sind` (like most mathematical functions in MATLAB) returns a matrix of the same size, applying the function to each element. Use `sum` to get the sum of a vector.

```
sins=1/3*(sum(sind(a)));
```